# Scheme Function to Count Atomic Elements in a List

Tags: list, recursion, scheme

I am trying to write a simple recursive definition in Scheme (LISP).

The goal is to count the number of atomic elements in a list and recursively count internal list atoms as well.

For example:

```
(num_items '((a b) c d))
```

should return:

```
4
```

because `"a"`, `"b"`, `"c"`, and `"d"` are the four atomic elements in the lists/sub-lists.

My code so far is as follows:

```
(define (num_items X)
(cond 
    ((null? X) 0)
    (list? (car X) (+ (num_items(car X)) (num_items(cdr X))))
    (else (+ 1 (num_items(cdr X))))
))

(display(num_items '((a b) c d)))
```

The error is thrown on the 4th line:

```
(list? (car X) (+ (num_items(car X)) (num_items(cdr X))))
```

As far as I can tell, the `(num_items(car X))` recursion in the addition seems to be causing the error.  If I replace that part of the line with a `1` for example to get:

```
(list? (car X) (+ 1 (num_items(cdr X))))
```

Then the code compiles and runs, but then it doesn't solve the problem.

I am using [Compile Online](http://www.compileonline.com/execute_scheme_online.php) to test/run my code.  The error it throws is:

```
$gosh main.scheme

gosh: "error": pair required, but got a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pair of parentheses are missing in the fourth line, try this:

```
(define (num_items X)
  (cond 
    ((null? X) 0)
    ((list? (car X)) (+ (num_items (car X)) (num_items (cdr X))))
    (else (+ 1 (num_items (cdr X))))))
```

Other than that, the code is fine. Just a minor suggestion: don't close parentheses in a separate line, close them all at the end. Also, notice that you can replace `list?` with `pair?` (or `cons?`, depending on which one is available in your interpreter). This is cheaper than testing if the value is a list.